# Bluemixの携帯傾きセンサーについて

Tags: bluemix

BluemixのIoTデモの定番である、携帯傾きセンサーアドレスの phonesensor.mybluemix.netは、Android でも動きますか？

Answer (score 1):

Androidで動いています
Lollipop更新前の4.4.4です

Answer (score 1):

FYI ですが、傾きセンターのアプリケーションはWEBアプリケーションです。ソースはこちらにあります。

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-html5-phone